# Not able to show ng -bootstrap toast through interceptor or constructor of any component angular. but it works fine by clicking on button

Tags: angular

I am trying to show toaster through interceptor in angular by calling toastService function.
this works fine in component and even the toast of the interceptor is also shown once I click on button inside component but that is not working inside interceptor
actually the toasts array is filled even when calling in interceptor but it only takes effect in component but not interceptor
how I can fix it?

see how I calling it in interceptor

```
this.toastService.show('Some Error occurred while processing your request. please contact iCM tech support', {classname: 'bg-danger text-light', delay: 3000 , autohide: true, headertext: 'Error'});
```

the same line show toast in any component when I add. but not inside interceptor

this is my interceptor code

```
 constructor(private toastService: ToastService){
    // debugger
  }
 intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!req.headers.has("Content-Type")) {
      req = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      });
    }
    this.token = localStorage.token ? localStorage.token : "";
    req = this.addAuthenticationToken(req);

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error && error.status === 401) {
            
          
        } 
        else {
          if (error && (error.status == 0 || error.status == -1)) {
            // code...
            //DO NOTHING
          }
          else{
            //SHOW TOASTERS HERE
            // debugger
            this.toastService.show('Some Error occurred while processing your request. please contact iCM tech support', {classname: 'bg-danger text-light', delay: 3000 , autohide: true, headertext: 'Error'});
            return throwError(error);   
          }
        }
      })
    ) as Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
  }
```

clicking on red button also show toast of interceptor that was not shown in interceptor

[image]

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No not any error. even If this is called 5 times then toasters not show . But If I call the 6th time from component by clicking on button then all 6 toasters are shown up

Comment: can you provide more lines of code? Maybe the part of your interceptor that you use the `toastService`

Comment: yes I added in question

Comment: see when I click on red button then toaster that supposed to show from the interceptor show. but it not show when it was called through interceptor

Comment: @profanis
I also added image, you can see

Comment: hmm it's odd. Which service/pakcage do you use? I want to give it a try on my end

Comment: I created my own service. custom service. If you want I can provide you code

Comment: Not too much code it is

Comment: as far as I think it is not issue related to interceptor. it is angular related stuff that component only takes effect from component maybe and not interceptors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220878/discussion-between-profanis-and-ali-hussain).

Comment: that is not related to interceptor. even if I call the toaster.Service.show inside any other component constructor it is not showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was with the change detection not working
actually sometimes we need manually to detect change in angular whenever changing something externally or so

```
import {Component, TemplateRef, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastService} from '../toast.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toasts',
  templateUrl: "./toasts.component.html",
  host: {'[class.ngb-toasts]': 'true'},
})
export class ToastComponent {
  public toasts:any = [];
  constructor(private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef, public toastService: ToastService) {
        let that = this;
        setInterval(() => {
            if (that.toastService.toasts.length > 0) {
                console.log("called")
                that.chRef.detectChanges();
            }
        }, 1500);
  }
}
```

so I used ChangeDetectorRef to force change detection after an interval and then it started detecting change and updated data in component started showing

the ***detectChanges*** is dowing all for me and I am now successful after spending two hours of time